# Visual studio c++ adding copy of file to solution

Tags: c++, file, copy

When using c# I would just add an existing item and it would put a copy of it in my project. I want to do this with a project in c++ but whenever I do it by default it seems to add it as a link, giving errors if I move the original files. The add as link option does not appear in the drop down on add like normally. How can I add copies of these files (header files and source files) so that new copies are made in the project.

Comment: Seeing some of the code you are using to connect to the header and source files will give us much better information and allow for better (and generally quicker) answers.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer is to copy the file(s) manually to your desired solution folder, then use add existing item.